# Nnginx map urls to proxy_pass in one location directive

Tags: nginx, proxypass, redirection

I have multiple node websockets that are available through a url matching the UNIX socket paths. Instead of duplicating the location directive, I would like to have something like a list of Urls that will be used as socket name. Using a regex does not work, because I need the path for the socket name.

Currently I'm using this location:

```
location /application1/
{
   proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/nodejs/application1;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

the goal is to have something like:

```
$list = [app1, app2, app3];           #list of possible names
location /$list/   #match all names in the list
{
   proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/nodejs/$list_matched;   #use matched name
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Basically every URL in a list should be redirected to the socket with the same name.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Please expand on your question, it's not clear what your end state is. Give examples.

Comment: I added more details to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~* /(<regexp>)/ {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/nodejs/$1;   #use matched name
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Comment: The `$1` was exactly what was missing. In combination with `location ~ /(app1|app2|app3)/` to match all hostnames it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regular expression. Something like this should work, but you will have to work out the regular expression yourself. There are plenty of tutorials and [regular expression experimentation sites](https://regex101.com/).

```
location ~ (app1|app2|app3)$ {
```